# Help Center - Request to move advanced-search-parameters-jobs page to Jobs subsection

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, help-center

I would like to request that the help center's [advanced-search-parameters-jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advanced-search-parameters-jobs) page be moved from section "Our Model" to the proper section "Stack Overflow Jobs".

This is to avoid confusion with advanced search parameters for the [main Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

> [image]

This is also an issue when [searching for "advanced search"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=advanced+search) in the help center:

Guess which result is about advanced search for the main Q&A?

> [image]

<sup>Hint: it's not #1 or #2</sup>